# Perform action only if two buttons are clicked

Tags: android

This is the first time I'm ever dabbling in Android development so please bear with me.

My requirement is this:

I have two buttons on screen, A and B. If the user presses **both** buttons (order doesn't matter), I need another page to be displayed. Pressing either A or B should do nothing.

Is this possible? If so, how would I achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible if you take a flag. (boolean)
You should set a flag in your button listeners.

```
    public class Mtest extends Activity {
      Button b1;
      Button b2;
      boolean flag_1 = false;
      boolean flag_2 = false;
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
        b1.setOnClickListener(myhandler1);
        b2.setOnClickListener(myhandler2);

      }
      View.OnClickListener myhandler1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          // it was the 1st button
          flag_1 = true;
          doSomething();
        }
      };

      View.OnClickListener myhandler2 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          // it was the 2nd button
          flag_2 = true;
          doSomething();
        }
      };



    }

    public void doSomething(){
       if(flag_1 && flag_2)
       {
         //DO SOMETHING
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but where should this go? My main file is called Quiz.java and its associated xml file is called activity_quiz.xml. Should I create a new file for the Mtest class? If so, how do I link that to my main Quiz.java file?

Answer (score 0):

Create two `boolean`'s like `button1isClicked`and `button2isClicked`,then set an `onClickListener` for each Button. When the the Button is clicked set the value of these two `boolean`'s to true, then simply create an `if()` statement that will chekc to see if both buttons have been clicked, like this:

```
if(button1isClicked == true && button2isClicked == true){
//display your new page
}
```